# Broadcast a word to an xmm register

Tags: assembly, x86, sse

I need to move a 16-bit word eight times into an xmm register for SSE operations

E. g.: I'd like to work with the 16-bit word ABCD to the xmm0 register, so that the final result looks like

```
ABCD | ABCD | ABCD | ABCD | ABCD | ABCD | ABCD | ABCD
```

I want to do this in order to use the `paddw` operation later on. So far I've found the `pushfd` operation which does what I want to do, but only for double words (32-bit). `pshufw` only works for - if I'm not mistaken - 64-bit registers. Is there the operation I am looking for, or do I have to emulate it in some way with multiple `pshufw`?

Comment: Which SSE versions are you targeting?

Comment: Also if you only want to do a single `paddw` and your input/output is not consecutive in memory it would probably be better to just add them using scalar instructions.

Comment: @Jester I am going through a loop of `paddw` instructions afterwards.

Comment: If your `ABCD` is a constant you can do `mov eax, 0xABCDABCD; movd xmm0, eax; pshufd xmm0, xmm0, 0` Obviously you can also load it from memory.

Comment: @fuz I'm targeting SSE2

Comment: @Jester so that's the problem. It's not a constant but stored in `cx`. Do you think I should do some shift so that `ecx` contains e. g. `0xABCDABCD`?

Comment: `movd xmm0, ecx; pshuflw xmm0, xmm0, 0; pshufd xmm0, xmm0, 0`. Alternatively `imul ecx, ecx, 0x00010001; movd xmm0, ecx; pshufd xmm0, xmm0, 0` (assuming top 16 bits of `ecx` are zero). Note I haven't checked latencies and throughput, just throwing out ideas :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the desired goal by performing a shuffle and then an unpack.  In NASM syntax:

```
    # load 16 bit from memory into all words of xmm0
    # assuming 16-byte alignment
    pshuflw xmm0, [mem], 0 # gives you [ M, M, M, M, ?, ?, ?, ? ]
    punpcklwd xmm0, xmm0   # gives you [ M, M, M, M, M, M, M, M ]
```

Note that this reads 16 bytes from `mem` and thus **requires 16-byte alignment**.

Only the first 2 bytes are actually used.  If the number is not in memory or you can't guarantee that reading past the end is possible, use something like this:

```
    # load ax into all words of xmm0
    movd      xmm0, eax                  ; or movd xmm0, [mem]  4-byte load
    pshuflw   xmm0, xmm0, 0
    punpcklwd xmm0, xmm0
```

---

With AVX2, you can use a [`vpbroadcast*`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpbroadcast) broadcast load or a broadcast from a register source.  The destination can be YMM if you like.

```
    vpbroadcastw  xmm0, [mem]            ; 16-bit load + broadcast
```

Or

```
    vmovd         xmm0, eax
    vpbroadcastw  xmm0, xmm0
```

Memory-source broadcasts of 1 or 2-byte elements still decode to a load+shuffle uop on Intel CPUs, but broadcast-loads of 4-byte or 8-byte chunks are even cheaper: handled in the load port with no shuffle uop needed.

Either way this is still cheaper than 2 separate shuffles like you need without AVX2 or SSSE3 `pshufb`.

Comment: Both your and @Jester 's suggestions of doing `imul ecx, ecx, 0x00010001; movd xmm0, ecx; pshufd xmm0, xmm0, 0` work perfectly. Which one should I choose? Is there any difference in performance?

Comment: Surprisingly, `imul` has latency 3 on cpus I have looked at, while `pshuflw` only 1.

Comment: @Jester: yup, it's a tradeoff between latency and execution-port pressure  on the shuffle port.  Intel Haswell and later only have 1 per clock shuffle throughput (port 5 only), so if you're doing a lot of shuffling this can be a problem.  As setup for uops that run on other ports, it's fine.  Multiply latency of 3c (and throughput of 1c fully pipelined) is really very good when you consider how much work that is.  AMD Bulldozer-family has 4c latency for 32-bit multiply, and 6c latency for 64-bit multiply, neither fully pipelined.